# Trouble storing names into an object using for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

i'm having trouble printing out the names in the for loop. This is what I have. I'm trying to print the names of the passengers who are the ages of less or equal to 14.

```
x <- c()
for(i in length(titanicDataset$name)){
if(titanicDataset$age[i] <= 14){
x[i] <- titanicDataset$name[i]
}
}
print(x)
```

it just prints NULL

Comment: `print()` should be inside loop before last curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length` returns a single value.  Instead, it should be `1:length` or `seq_along`

```
x <- character(nrow(titanicDataset))
for(i in seq_along(titanicDataset$name)) {
      if(titanicDataset$age[i] <= 14){
      x[i] <- titanicDataset$name[i]
   }
  }
```

---

We don't need a loop for this as these are vectorized

```
with(titanicDataset, name[age <= 14])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My brain is at its limit right now  haha

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify then range for loop (`1:length(...)`),

and concatenate new data to `x`:

```r
x <- c()
for(i in 1:length(titanicDataset$name)){
  if(titanicDataset$age[i] <= 14){
    x <- c(x, titanicDataset$name[i])
  }
}
print(x)
```